# PHP $_POST not working with 2 dropdown menus

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a little script that displays the value of the 2th dropdown menu. Only when I post the value, always the first item of the menu is displayed to the PHP script. What is wrong?

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    function fctCheck(food) {
            var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
            }
            document.getElementById(food).style.display = "block";
        }//]]>  
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <select id="food" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
            <option value="keuze">Choose option</option> 
            <option value="Alanya Gazipasa Airport (GZP)">Alanya Gazipasa Airport (GZP)</option>
            <option value="Antalya Airport (AYT)">Antalya Airport (AYT)</option>
        </select><br>

        <select id="keuze" name="subselector" disabled style="width: 120px;">
            <option value="vanilla">Choose option</option>
        </select>  

        <select id="Alanya Gazipasa Airport (GZP)" name="subselector" style="display:none; width: 120px;">
            <option>Alanya Avsallar</option>
            <option>Alanya Cikcilli</option>
            <option>Alanya Demirtas</option>
            <option>Alanya Kargijak</option>
            <option>Alanya Kestel</option>
        </select>  

        <select id="Antalya Airport (AYT)" name="subselector" style="display:none; width: 120px;">
            <option>Alanya Avsallar</option>
            <option>Alanya Cikcilli</option>
            <option>Alanya Demirtas</option>
            <option>Alanya Incekum</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['subselector'];
echo "$value";
?>
```

Comment: This is because they all have the same name. Change this and it should work

Comment: you can use same names with `[]` ends. Then you get array in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change the name filed bcoz u want name selector you have to disabled the unrelated 
select box because if i hide that element but it is executed not shown to use

try this its working ok

```
     <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
           function fctCheck(food) {
           var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
           for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
               elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
               elems.item(i).disabled = true;
           }
          document.getElementById(food).style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById(food).disabled = false;
          }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two form elements with the same name. One will over write the other. You need to give them each a unique name and then access them by that unique name in your PHP.